# Unable to count has_many through records for user based on boolean value & association Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to aggregate and count records based on an association between 3 associations in a clean manner.

Okay, to begin I have:

**AdminUser**

```
has_many :jobs 
has_many :job_applications, through: :jobs
```

**JobApplications**

```
has_one :job_application_status_profile
```

**job_application.rb**

```
class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :job
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :job_application_status_profile, dependent: :destroy
 after_create :create_job_application_status_profile
end
```

**job.rb**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :admin_user
 has_many :job_applications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**admin_user.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :job_applications, through: :jobs
end
```

I need to count how many records job application_status profiles have is_review_complete through jobs -> job_applications

```
current_admin_user.jobs.where(job_applications: {job_application_status_profile: {is_review_complete: false}}).size
```

Simply put, but I get an error while doing that.

How can I count through the relationships with the fastest approach?

Comment: What do you get from `current_user.jobs.where(job_applications: {job_application_status_profile: {is_review_complete: false}}).to_sql` ?

Comment: "SELECT \"jobs\".* FROM \"jobs\" WHERE \"jobs\".\"user_id\" = 2 AND \"job_application_status_profile\".\"is_review_complete\" = FALSE"

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "job_application_status_profile")

Comment: You need to add a `.joins(job_applications: :job_application_status_profile)` or something like that.  Add your model has_many / belongs_to definitions to give us more of an idea.

Comment: I cleaned up the solution a little bit. But, the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing includes.
Try something like this:

```
current_user.jobs.includes(job_applications: 
[:job_application_status_profile]).where(job_applications: 
{job_application_status_profiles: {is_review_complete: false}}).size
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: I'm getting ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "job_application_status_profile")

Comment: job_application_status_profile in where should be plural and not singular(so job_application_status_profiles). My mistake. I edit my answer. I have similar tables and association in my project and works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `eager_load`. Try something like this

```
current_user.jobs.eager_load(job_applications: 
[:job_application_status_profile]).where(job_applications: 
{job_application_status_profile: {is_review_complete: false}}).size
```

Ref doc: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-eager_load